# marshmallow and personal security/privacy

Tags: security, 6.0-marshmallow, privacy

I've been reading the [news](http://www.nbcnews.com/storyline/san-bernardino-shooting/judge-forces-apple-help-unlock-san-bernardino-shooter-iphone-n519701) in the US about a court order for Apple to help the FBI bypass the security check present on devices running iOS8+. Since iOS8, Apple has stopped storing encryption keys on the cloud.

I'm just wondering how does this apply to Android. I believe Nexus devices that came with Marshmallow out of the box (6P and 5x) have full disk encryption thus these will have the same security as iOS8+ devices.

How about those that were upgrade to Marshmallow? I know my G3 was upgraded to Marshmallow but encryption is turned off. Also, does turning it on make a difference? Or perhaps the 6P and 5x has extra hardware so encryption keys aren't stored in the cloud?

Thanks for reading and your replies :)

Comment: Encryption keys are never stored in the cloud on Android, and I seriously doubt they were for iOS. iCloud's *backups* can be encrypted, but that's a completely different key and the goal is to keep the data safe while it's at rest on Apple's servers. Storing the device encryption key in the cloud would be an incredibly poor design.

Comment: See https://source.android.com/security/encryption/index.html#storing_the_encrypted_key